# DJango Migration Classes

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have an app called `students` and I have a multiple class(`Class1, Class2,...`) in my model.py. When I run the `python manage.py migrate` it will create a new table(students_class1, students_class2,...) in my database.

And now, my question is, is it possible to skip a specific class when migrating the app? like I don't want to create a table called `students_class2`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`managed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#managed) in the model's `Meta` class.

According to the docs:

> If False, no database table creation or deletion operations will be performed for this model. This is useful if the model represents an existing table or a database view that has been created by some other means. This is the only difference when managed=False. All other aspects of model handling are exactly the same as normal.

In case you already created migration, add `'managed': False` to [`CreateModel`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#createmodel)'s options:

```
from django.db.migrations import Migration as DjangoMigration, CreateModel


class Migration(DjangoMigration):
    operations = [
        CreateModel(
            name='ModelName',
            fields=[
                # Model's fields.
            ],
            options={
                # Other options.
                'managed': False
            }
        )
    ]
```

Also, consider using [`db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#db-table) for choosing an appropriate table name.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you! Gonna check this out.

Comment: I tried it but when I tried to migrate it, it says "table already exist". Yes, I already have a table in the database, that's why I don't want to migrate it because I would need to rename my current table in order to run the migrate successfully.

Comment: @aldesabido Well, you have to edit your migration class in case it already exists. I will add this to my answer in order to cover that case.

Comment: @aldesabido Also, it's not necessary to rename you existing table in order to run `migrate` successfully. You can change default table name using [`db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#db-table).

Comment: db_table works! thank you! I am now reading the Docs for Meta. Seems like there are so many stuff that I still need to know. Thank you :)